# Set 00000 Input Transparent Color with GeoServer Rest API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, curl, gsconfig

I need to change parameters (Input Transparent Color) from layers in GeoServer. I have a lot of images to do it. So, I need to do this edit using GeoServer REST API.

I did the code below but it doesn't work.

```bsh
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<coverage><parameters><entry><string>*InputTransparentColor*</string><string>000000</string></entry></parameters><enabled>true</enabled></coverage>" http://localhost:$81/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sentinel2/coveragestores/$covareganame/coverages/$covareganame.xml
```

Is it possible to change layer's parameters from the curl commands?
What's wrong in my script it not change input transparent color to '00000'?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```bsh
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<coverage><parameters><entry><string>InputTransparentColor</string><string>#000000</string></entry></parameters></coverage>"  http://$IP:PORT/geoserver/rest/workspaces/$WORKSPACENAME/coveragestores/$RESOURCENAME/coverages/LAYERNAME.xml
```